# Can time in space be years faster than on Earth?

Tags: spacetime, time-dilation, estimation, solar-system, galaxies

Is it possible that in some distant solar system from another galaxy, time will be dramatically different from our Earth time, with years passing far faster than on Earth time?

Comment: Time in your reference frame is what you are accustomed to, no matter how fast or slow time moves in other reference frames.

Comment: Related - [Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178417/37364)

Answer (score 2):

> Omar Kashabash asked: *"Is it possible that in some distant solar
> system from another galaxy, time will be dramatically different from
> our Earth time, with years passing far faster than on Earth time?"*

For an ideal [comoving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_and_proper_distances) observer 13.8 billion years elapsed since the big bang, which is a little more than in our frame, but not by much since the earth's [peculiar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peculiar_velocity#Cosmology) velocity relative to the CMB is already low and its gravitational field rather weak, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWncwRTMKkI&t=216s).

In the close field of very high electric charges time runs even faster than in vacuum, but astrophysically and cosmologically those would be rather rare scenarions, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/724520/where-in-the-universe-does-time-pass-fastest-relative-to-time-on-earth/725694#725694).

There are clocks that can tick far slower though, for example in the close field of a black hole or in the frame of a Neutrino travelling at almost c, so if you come across a Neutrino that was created at the big bang its proper time will be much less than 13.8 billion years.

Finding an object with a proper time much higher than 13.8 billion years is on the other hand rather improbable, since the large electric charges necessary to speed time up do not really exist in our over all neutral universe.